# Find object in array of object by keys and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I need to return part of the object which meet some condition.
I get API response with the following example:

```
const response: ApiResponse = {
          valid: true,
          start: true,
          stop: false
        };
```

And based on that response I need to check my configuration object and check if there is some object witch meets the response. My config looks like this (can be modified if there is a better way to model it)

```
public readonly modalDataConfig: ModalDataConfig[] = [
    {
      conditions: [
        {
          start: true,
          valid: true,
        },
      ],
      p1: {
        title: `Name p1 A`,
        description: `description p1 A`,

      },
      p2: {
        title: `Name p2 B`,
        description: `description p2 B`,

      },
    },
    {
      conditions: [
        {
          valid: false,
          stop: true,
        },
      ],
      p1: {
        title: `Name p1 C`,
        description: `description p1 C`,

      },
      p2: {
        title: `Name p2 C`,
        description: `description p2 C`,

      },
    },
    {
      conditions: [
        {
          start: false,
          valid: false,
        },
      ],
      p1: {
        title: `Name p1 D`,
        description: `description p1 D`,

      },
      p2: {
        title: `Name p2 D`,
        description: `description p2 D`,

      },
    },
  ];
```

So I need to check if there is an object inside of the modalDataConfig.conditions which meets the response conditions. If yes I need to return either p1 or p2 from that object.
I get always 3 conditions from API but my configuration condition usually uses just 2 of them. So I need to check keys and values.
In the example I should get the first object since it conditions array has start: true and valid: true.
[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAAglgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYgMIHsIBMxRg4gDeoIAzlEnFAPwBcIARllgDYxIQDc5AbknZhcTVhy69yVLAAdGLNp258AvsFCRYiVOgCyWXEIAiSaqXKEonJlTiQA5nxAhcMCinuzCOW1HsQThrq4NDwyGggBkbsptTYEAhgDhYuKDj4PhAUTAmZRBAA2gC6ziCyAIxM0SZmSGWyAEzVhrXUahogMBAArgC2IAAKcIY9aHCpQxUgALwgAOSV8wA05IONswtNK8DqmmE6kQCCsmAASu6yOBToZC6CwqKKEirS1LRiSpJlMrKfL1IQih2EgKBQQAAxJDMewoMxYCZ3EDpbL%20MZQBEACgAlKQ9i5ZD1mMIUCA4FxcDh2ABPEB9VqxOoJJIOFoxOJIZnJEqbQrkFxIlxpDIEAo5EB8oVSybSoVUGhQJhomCrWVSh4iJVwHoq-nS1Sq6XFQ1SypMQXSqw2EAAAwAckg%20uhKiAjjaTdK3B4vFkmDavZ4wN4CuVpm7VnqXAbI%20VmjLLQRrfbHc6NgAhd0xlwBn0FP05oNZWMgDMR2XRqUVoUW4V4UXXJiStU16Uap7Idg3D2y35anXdoVVqXGmNm%20NSq0wP0Op2hzCZtWudyB4O%20W0F1cQOcYTMxodCprmrMgSfTlPFncD7PL3Nr-03wshprzsv6j37lso-INiXHltS%20UPhADsu2Pe4hE1YChFAxd9xcEdZTHf8T0TKdbRnZ1pmMBc1Q3X11wfTc52w19KwHQ9xyFU90PPZ8SOPPC8wI71H2IOjd3Ld9DVKTpyiJElkQACxgFAAGsakZahMSQU4LgoK5sjQk5zkua4VWRHBYAAD0VIYRlwMZ4GxO4USoMl3B6dgoDmKBBLACgADp6XZJkcBZBykis%20BMUxFEWQYCSOS5BxsRmAA%20QVTIkBz2CwBxfLc5JlgWPzknmbFgHJKAejgLdUocByv3rbIPLALy4B8ggYD6Bg8mK0KIvIKLOBiuLMSqvoMpcLKcq3cBYD6By21mGY5hklT5LUoaINwEAADI5v66rpseEaxtk1TFIcwCoF2LrB32lwAHojo07Joti%20LyQoSyoGWeZrtu9LMpgbLcvMm6rLKPY9lMqAzu0-65mGUZxgcwYKj4P6QGpJhlLkhSbk2ZDwMePtdUXFwdqYECMcx3sT21GBj1UPhgGhrTNggGAAHdIWhWF4QqjLyeuf6gZALTCuEsTArqTFqWWFFAexPgTrOigLraqBsSAA)
Edit:
I need to return p1 or p2 from the correct object based on the param which I know beforehand. So in the example I can assume:

```
const context = Producer.P1;
```

where AppContext is enum

```
 enum Producer {
  P1 = 'p1',
  P2 = 'p2',
}
```

Comment: I edited question. when it comes to config variable it can be change to whatever make better sense.

Comment: Why you should get the first object?  Conditions array has valid: `true` and  start: `true` but  response has valid: `true` and start`false`.

Comment: @AlexandrBelan right, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

We can also simplify my solution based on a commenter's suggestion! This function removes the need to use 1/0 and simply checks if all the elements in the array are truthy.

```js
const checkResponse = (modalDataConfig, response) => {
  let res = []
  for (const conf of modalDataConfig) {
    let cond = conf.conditions
    let isSame = Object.keys(cond)
      .map(key => response?.[key] == cond[key]).every(Boolean)
    if (isSame) res.push(conf)
  }

  return res
}
```

### Note

In my solution, I am assuming that we only care if the key:value pairs in the conditions of the config are the same as the key:value pairs in the response, and not the other way around. This means that if there exists a key in response but not in the config, we do not use that key for our similarity check.

### Steps

1. I would first change how the ModelDataConfig is modeled, by replacing the value of the `condition` key to just be an object instead of an array of objects.
2. I will first iterate through each element in `modelDataConfig`
3. Within the `conditions` object of each element, I compare its key:value with the `response`, by checking 2 conditions - (1) if the key exists in `response` and if the value of that key is the same in both the element and `response`. If it satisfies both of this condition, I return a 1, else a 0. At the end, I get an array of 1s and 0s.
4. For the `response` to satisfy the `conditions`, there can only be 1s in the array, because having a zero means that either they key doesn't even exist in the `response`, or the keys have different values. To check if there are only 1s, I reduce the array by using a bitwise AND operator.
5. If the final result after reduction is 1, it means that the particular element of the `modelDataConfig` is the one you are looking for.

### Example

```js
const modalDataConfig = [{
    conditions: {
      start: true,
      valid: true,
    },
    p1: {
      title: `Name p1 A`,
      description: `description p1 A`,

    },
    p2: {
      title: `Name p2 B`,
      description: `description p2 B`,

    },
  },
  {
    conditions: {
      valid: false,
      stop: true,
    },
    p1: {
      title: `Name p1 C`,
      description: `description p1 C`,

    },
    p2: {
      title: `Name p2 C`,
      description: `description p2 C`,

    },
  },
  {
    conditions: {
      start: false,
      valid: false,
    },
    p1: {
      title: `Name p1 D`,
      description: `description p1 D`,

    },
    p2: {
      title: `Name p2 D`,
      description: `description p2 D`,

    },
  },
  {
    conditions: {
      start: false,
      valid: true,
    },
    p1: {
      title: `Name p1 D`,
      description: `description p1 D`,

    },
    p2: {
      title: `Name p2 D`,
      description: `description p2 D`,

    },
  },
];



const checkResponse = (modalDataConfig, response) => {
  let res = []
  for (const conf of modalDataConfig) {
    let cond = conf.conditions
    let isSame = Object.keys(cond)
      .map(key => key in response && response[key] == cond[key] ? 1 : 0)
      .reduce((a, b) => a & b, 1)

    if (isSame) res.push(conf)
  }

  return res
}

const response1 = {
  valid: true,
  start: false,
  stop: true
};
console.log('Results with response1:')
console.log(checkResponse(modalDataConfig, response1))

const response2 = {
  valid: false,
  stop: true
};
console.log('Results with response2:')
console.log(checkResponse(modalDataConfig, response2))
```

Comment: What is `a & b`?

Comment: Ok I'm trying to understand, I think your function can be shortened as `.map(key => response?.[key] == cond[key]).every(Boolean)`

Comment: @CristianTraìna `a & b` performs a [bitwise AND operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND).

Comment: Yes I got it, it's pretty unusual using 1/0 in place of true/false in JavaScript. We already have an array method to check if all the elements are truthy, better rely on that :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna That's true! I added your shortened version in my answer :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To find an object that satisfies conditions, you need decompose each `conditions` object into `key` and `value` and compare their result with the target value in the `ApiResponse`

```js
modalDataConfig=[{conditions:[{start:true,valid:true}],p1:{title:`Name p1 A`,description:`description p1 A`},p2:{title:`Name p2 B`,description:`description p2 B`}},{conditions:[{valid:false,stop:true}],p1:{title:`Name p1 C`,description:`description p1 C`},p2:{title:`Name p2 C`,description:`description p2 C`}},{conditions:[{start:false,valid:false}],p1:{title:`Name p1 D`,description:`description p1 D`},p2:{title:`Name p2 D`,description:`description p2 D`}}];

ApiResponse = {valid: true, start: true, stop: true};

const { p1, p2 } = modalDataConfig.find(({ conditions }) => 
     Object.entries(conditions.at(0))
     .every(([key, value]) => ApiResponse[key] === value));

console.log('P1 is:', p1, 'P2 is:', p2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```